# MongoDB: How to search array consist nothing outside of specific values?

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

Let's say that I have a set of data below:

```
{_id: "something", array: ["a", "b", "c", "d"]},  // 1
{_id: "something", array: ["a", "b", "d"]},  // 2
{_id: "something", array: ["b", "c", "d"]},  // 3
{_id: "something", array: ["a", "d"]},  // 4
{_id: "something", array: ["a", "b"]},  // 5
{_id: "something", array: ["d"]},  // 6
{_id: "something", array: ["c"]},  // 7
{_id: "something", array: []},  // 8
{_id: "something"},  // 9
{_id: "something", array: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", etc...]},  // 10
```

I want to find the documents that have the array consist nothing outside of "a" and "d" in the array. So the wanted output should be 4th, 6th, 8th and 9th from the data. How should I write the query?

Both $in and $nin could not get what I want (as using $nin will require me to input too much possibilities in the query).

Another note, I am using MongoDB v3.2 with Mongoose.

Addon note after receiving answers: 
- P.S. In this example, "a" and "d" is just example of 2 exclusion. However in actual implementation, it is a value inserted choosed by user. So it does not limit to 2 exclusion, which could later be "b", "c" and "d", or even more values base on user input.

Comment: `.find({ "something": { "$all": ["a","d"], "$size": 2 } }`. It's a pretty logical case that ALL are matched and the array only has the `2` elements which were used for the match. Add `$or` conditions for the single and empty/null cases

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks. However, in my actual implementation, the number of 'exception value' can be differ base on user input. So, it could quickly get messy when the amount of value that I want to exclude in the filter increased.

Comment: You really should not ask abstract questions. If you have a "real scenario" then show the real scenario. You clearly are not so that's why I comment, because I simply don't have the time for 'back and forth'. Ask what you mean if you expect an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will work:

```
db.examples.aggregate({
    $addFields: { // add a new field that holds...
        diff: { // ...all array values that are outside your allowed values
            $setDifference: [ "$array", [ "a", "d" ] ]
        }
    }
}, {
    $match: { // and use the newly added field to filter the result set
        $or: [ { diff: null }, { diff: [] } ]
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution would be:

```
use stackoverflow-example

db.examples.insertMany([{text: "something", array: ["a", "b", "c", "d"]},  // 1)
  {text: "something", array: ["a", "b", "d"]},  // 2
  {text: "something", array: ["b", "c", "d"]},  // 3
  {text: "something", array: ["a", "d"]},  // 4
  {text: "something", array: ["a", "b"]},  // 5
  {text: "something", array: ["d"]},  // 6
  {text: "something", array: ["c"]},  // 7
  {text: "something", array: []},  // 8
  {text: "something"},  // 9
  {text: "something", array: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]}]
)




db.examples.find({
  $or: [{ 
    $and: [{ array: 'a' }, { array: 'd' }, {array: { $size: 2 }}] 
  }, {
    $and: [{ array: 'a' }, {array: { $size: 1 }}] 
  }, {
    $and: [{ array: 'd' }, {array: { $size: 1 }}] 
  }, {
    array: { $size: 0 }
  }, {
    array: { $exists: false }
  }]
})
```

this returns the required objects. I'm sure a nicer solution can be found